# Call funtion when Odoo record created

Tags: python, odoo-11

Actually,I want to send message to topic with use of google cloud pubsub when any record created/updated at Odoo server

I override create function as below

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    values = self._remove_reified_groups(values)
    user = super(Users, self).create(values) // created and return id just like res.users(67,)
    group_multi_company = self.env.ref('base.group_multi_company', False)
    if group_multi_company and 'company_ids' in values:
        if len(user.company_ids) <= 1 and user.id in group_multi_company.users.ids:
            group_multi_company.write({'users': [(3, user.id)]})
        elif len(user.company_ids) > 1 and user.id not in group_multi_company.users.ids:
            group_multi_company.write({'users': [(4, user.id)]})

    # Publish message to subscriber
    pubsub = PubSub()

    // Here I used own middleware service which is used for CRUD opertion on 
       Odoo model
    // Below API return record of model 'res.users'
    // Here user.id return 67
    req = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/users/' + str(user.id))
    fetch_user = req.text // response return user not found because record nor save in table
    result = pubsub.publish_message_on_topic(self.project_id, self.topic_name, fetch_user)
    return user
```

In create function user created & its return id in user variable but its not save in table until 'return user'(last line of function) not run. I don't know how create functionality worked in Odoo?

So,I search on any event triggered when record created/updated so I will implement my pubsub logic to that function.

Any help or suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

odoo works like transaction untill transaction is not completed it didnot commit it.odoo calls create function and do all its functionality but it didnot reflect in database untill it returns the value, you will get its values in function but it didnot commit this in database untill function returns the value

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then any other solution for getting event after created/store record in the database? Our middleware API service which points to Odoo server for CRUD operations. After created record, I called our service API to fetch that record via record id and response published to pubsub topic.